# UNION two table minus duplicate records from second table by their ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables as following:

**Table1**

```
id    name  desc
----- ----- ---------
1     nd1   desc1
2     nd2   desc2
4     nd4   
7     nd7   desc7
```

**Table2**

```
id    name  desc     
----- ----- ---------
3     nd3   desc3
4     nd4   desc17   
5     nd5   desc5    
6     nd6   desc6    
7     nd7
```

What I need is all records from 1st table plus records from 2nd table that their ID does not exists in 1st table.

The data that I need is following:

**Result**

```
id    name  desc
----- ----- ---------
1     nd1   desc1
2     nd2   desc2
3     nd3   desc3
4     nd4   
5     nd5   desc5    
6     nd6   desc6    
7     nd7   desc7
```

Currently I am doing following:

```
SELECT
    id, name, desc FROM table1
UNION
SELECT
    id, name, desc FROM table2 
WHERE
  Id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1)
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You could look at full outer join but it really may not make any difference and it probably isn't more readable.

Comment: Try using `UNION ALL` instead and `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one:

Assuming `Table1` has a `PK` on `id`.

```
SELECT
    id, name, [desc]
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    id, name, [desc]
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE id = t2.id)
```

Comment: I think SQL engine will run this query the same way as mine, but `UNION ALL` makes it faster.

Comment: Yes. The difference is in the `UNION ALL` operator. This will eliminate the need for a `DISTINCT SORT` operation. See the query plan for more details.

Comment: [Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Actual Query Plan, this query is slightly more efficient than your example query with the UNION.

```
select
    case when t1.id is not null then t1.id else t2.id end id,
    case when t1.id is not null then t1.name else t2.name end name,
    case when t1.id is not null then t1.[desc] else t2.[desc] end [desc]
from
    table1 t1
    full outer join
        table2 t2
        on
            t1.id = t2.id
```

I haven't tested it on a large dataset, so I don't know what will happen then. This is the complete fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb95d/1

Comment: Your query is ignoring null value on table1 -> row 4 and also mixing column data from two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXCEPT` like `UNION`. But, it won't allow to show the rows, which is already present in first query.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of doubt that this is better but I believe its results are equivalent:

```
SELECT
    coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id, coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) as name,
    case when t1.id is not null then t1."desc" else t2."desc" end as "desc"
FROM
    table1 as t1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2 as t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```